# Date/time output has single quote in front of variable in Google Sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have some code to export some output to a Google Sheet. The command I am using for that is:

```py
row = [timestamp, float(temperature), float(humidity), current_temperature, current_humidity, current_pressure, weather_description]
sheet.insert_row(row, index)
```

The issue is that the timestamp variable is adding a single quote in front of itself when it is inserted into the sheet, but when using `print(timestamp)`, this quote is not there.

[image: date/time in cell in Google Sheets]

This makes it difficult because I cannot make any graphs with that quote in front of the output. The commands I am using for time are as follows:

```py
now = datetime.now()
timestamp = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y%l:%M:%S %p")
```

How can I get a timestamp without a single quote in front?

Answer (score 5):

Try `sheet.insert_row(row, index, value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')`.

By default, `value_input_option` will be `RAW`:

> The values the user has entered will not be parsed and will be stored as-is.

Use `USER_ENTERED`:

> The values will be parsed as if the user typed them into the UI. Numbers will stay as numbers, but strings may be converted to numbers, dates, etc. following the same rules that are applied when entering text into a cell via the Google Sheets UI.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption

Answer (score 2):

This is usually to indicate that the input is a string. I recommend to just insert the date using `datetime.now()` in this way google sheets will recognize it as a date rather than a string.

```py
timestamp = datetime.now()
row = [timestamp,float(temperature),float(humidity),current_temperature,current_humidity,current_pressure,weather_description]
sheet.insert_row(row, index)
```

**Edit:**

If you want a special date format in your sheet, you will need to use google sheets API and format the column accordingly. I recommend using the library `gspread` is really useful when it comes to google-sheets formatting and easy to use: [gspread docs](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

There is also another a special library to use gspread with pandas, I find it really useful as well: [gspread-pandas](https://gspread-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gspread_pandas.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, it errors out and only works if the variable I am pushing is a string or number. I am trying some other things, like epoch time, but I am unsure how to go around that with taking DST into account.

Answer (score -3):

To remove a character from a string, try using the String.split() function:

```
timestamp = timestamp.split("'")[1]
```

Comment: If you are removing a character from a string, there are fairly more options. Split is used to create a list from a string using a specific separator. Also, the comma is not inserted by @Aaron is added by google sheets when the row is inserted to the worksheet

Comment: For removing a character you could use ```timestamp.replace("'","")``` but is not going to work as the quote doesn't exist until is uploaded to google sheets.